# What needs be taken when backing up RoboForm?

Tags: roboform

When backing up RoboForm, does anything need be taken beyond the folder with files ("My RoboForm Data" by default)?

Having 100+ files that I must  not lose, I thought to check whether it is only "My RoboForm Data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. Just that folder.

You can also use RoboForm own Backup feature.
RoboForm menu **->** Options **->** **User Data** (on left list) **->** **Backup** button (under Backup and Restore).

It will inform you of what is going to be backed up. It's essentially the contents of your current RoboForm profile folder. By default it is under *My RoboForm data*. This folder contains all your current profiles.

So **the backup feature only backups the current profile** you have activated under RoboForm menu **->** Profiles. If you have more than one profile, best indeed to manually copy the *My RoboForm Data* folder.

Answer (score 0):

no need to have a back up anything except .rfp files folder